# How to correctly support arrow keys(↑↓←→) in C language stdin?

Tags: c, centos, stdin

I intend to develop a command line tool by C in the CentOS, with the following code:

```
// client.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char command[128];

    while (1)
    {
        memset(command, 0, 128);
        printf("cli > ");
        if (fgets(command, 128, stdin) != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(command, "exit\n") == 0)
                break;
            if (strcmp(command, "\n") == 0)
                continue;
            printf("do something ... %s", command);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program can works, but it doesn't execute the way I expect it to when I press the arrow keys.

I have finished typing a simple SQL and now the cursor stays after the semicolon.

```
[root@olap tests]# gcc client.c 
[root@olap tests]# ./a.out 
cli > selectt * from table_001;
```

But I misspelled the first keyword, it should be `select`, not `selectt`.
I am now pressing the left arrow key(←) to try to fix this mistake.
But the cursor didn't move properly as I expected, and it turned into the following.

```
[root@olap tests]# gcc client.c 
[root@olap tests]# ./a.out 
cli > selectt * from table_001;^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D
```

How should I modify the program to solve this problem?

I hope get help from people who are good at C development.

Thank you all

Comment: Consider using the _ncurses_ library or similar if you want to do special input/output in terminals.

Comment: Also consider *readline*, *editline*, *libedit*, *replxx* and the likes.

Comment: For Linux this is a strong candidate: https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html (note that licence is GPL)

Comment: Doing this yourself is a big undertaking, I suggest you write a separate module (.c and .h) which does line input, if you really want to do it yourself.

Comment: Key code sequences for arrows and other control keys depend on terminal where program run. If you don't want to use ncurses or readline, you should read terminal type from `TERM` environment variable and deal with termcap database directly.

Comment: Vaguely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69664058/6699433

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html) library with [getch](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h2-NOTES)

This sample code demonstrates how you can detect arrow keys and have a CLI prompt:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ch,i;
  char command[128];

  initscr();
  clear();
  noecho();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, true);

  while (1) {
      printw("cli> ");
      for (i=0;;i++) {
          ch=getch();
            
          if (ch==KEY_UP||ch==KEY_LEFT||ch==KEY_RIGHT||ch==KEY_DOWN) {
              /* printw("arrow keys pressed!");
              command[i]='\0';
              break; */
              i--;
          }
          else if (ch=='\n') {
              if (i>0)
                  printw("\n");
              command[i]='\0';
              break;
          }
          else {
              command[i]=ch;
              printw("%c",ch);
          }
      }
      if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0)
          break;
      else
          printw("%s\n", command);
        
    }
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `readline` library, you can find it [here](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). It supports arrow keys, a input history and input of any length (if configured).

```
char *input = readline("cli >");
if (input)
{
    if (strcmp(command, "exit\n") == 0)
    ...
    free(input);
}
```